# Find CSS Class or ID name of multi file with specific attribute

Tags: css, wordpress, notepad++, phpstorm

I work on a child-theme on WordPress. When I want to design my CSS child-theme, I need to collapse ID's and classes that had specific attribute from the parent theme.

For example: I want to collapse classes or Id's with `text-transform: uppercase;` like in this template:

```
.font-alt, .font-serif, .rotate

.font-alt {
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }

.font-serif {
    font-family: Volkhov, "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }

.large-text {
    font-size: 24px !important;
    }

.rotate {
    text-shadow: none !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;        
    }
```

How can I do this with Notepad++ or PhpStorm?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you intend to do or even what you mean by Collapsing classes?

Comment: Use sublime text. I guess that by collapse you are meaning find, right?

Comment: i want to collapse classes for overwriting.
i usually use (Notepad++ -> Find in files) so find my classes with a specific attribute then overwrite in a second CSS file.
this is time consuming for find css classes in a large theme.

Comment: how can i use this with sublime text?